Disabled Page Item Value Not Submitted on "Submit Page" in Oracle APEX
I'm encountering an issue in my Oracle APEX application where I have a select list page item that is dynamically disabled based on certain conditions. However, I've noticed that when this item is disabled and the page is submitted via "Submit Page," its value isn't sent to the server, causing difficulties in my subsequent PL/SQL processing logic.
Although the selected value is visually displayed correctly in the page item, it seems not to be transmitted to the server when the item is disabled.
Does anyone know why this happens and how I can address it? Is there a way to ensure that the page item value is sent to the server even when it's disabled? I appreciate any help or suggestions you can offer.
Execute JavaScript Code:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="P2_ACTION"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === "VR"){
            $('#P2_REISSUE').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#P2_REISSUE').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Disabled means it will not be handled/sent to server to be processed.
If you want the value to be shown and is sent to server, you can either use css property 'pointer-events:none' or you can add 'readonly' attribute to you item either using custom attributes property on page designer, or using Jquery:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="P2_ACTION"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === "VR"){
            $('#P2_REISSUE').attr('readonly', false);
        } else {
            $('#P2_REISSUE').attr('readonly', true);
        }
    });
});


For 'select list', the effective method will be using 'pointer-events:none'. Next challenge would be to also block the user from changing the value by keyboard.
